# Particles not loading

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

For some reason the particles I have applied will not render.

[image: Snapshot]

I'll be uploading the file soon

Comment: Here's the file http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45239/particles-not-loading

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I solved it. Cycles can't handle Halo. I need to switch to a Object render rather than a Halo render.